# Clicking a text tag to generate new hash

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

```
$num = rand(0, 10000);
$hash = password_hash($num, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array(
    'cost' => 6
));
```

Above is the hash

```
<p class="reg-code">Hash: <span><?php echo $hash; ?></span><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" id="refresh-code"></i></p>
```

I would like it so when someone clicks on the  tag that it generates a new hash into the span, how would I come across this?

I'm not sure how I would do this, like as a function in PHP or what.

Comment: You would have to do this in Javascript, as php is only executed once, unless you want to refresh the webpage

Comment: I find it ridiculous to create a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44037952/clicking-a-i-tag-to-generate-a-new-hash-wont-work) based on my answer without even upvoting anyone effort. You could have commented instead to get an updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's called Ajax:

```
<p class="reg-code">
  Hash: 
  <span id="hash"><?php echo $hash; ?></span>
  <i id="click" class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" id="refresh-code"></i>
</p>

$('#click').click(function(){
  $.post( "./path/to/hashscript.php", function( data ) {
    $( "#hash" ).html( data );
  });
});
```

You use JavaScript events to make a server request and update the page elements with the response. Your PHP script should echo the `$hash`.

```
echo password_hash($num, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 6]);
```

Comment: Hello,
Now when I click the <i> tag, the hash just disappears from the <span> but doesn't generate a new one?

Comment: Then most likely you are not calling the correct script. Try to fiddle around with `./path/to/hashscript.php`. Also, you should probably use element id's instead of classes.

Comment: @Oliver Updated the code to use I'd, as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

> Ajax allows you to send a request to another page without refreshing.
>   Check this part of the jQuery [Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

In your case, you set up like this (1st, include jQuery in the head of your page):

```
<p class="reg-code">Hash: <span></span>
<i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" id="refresh-code"></i></p>
```

*Note that the < span > that will handle the response is empty (but can show the original hash at the beginning. Its content will be replaced anyway when you click the link) when we start and that there's an ID attached to the refresh-link*

Then, you use jQuery:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#refresh-code").click(function(){ // click on element with ID 'refresh-code'

    $.ajax({ // method default is 'GET'
           url: "hash.exe.php", // the PHP page that will generate new hash
           success: function(html){ // if no PHP error 'html' is the response
                    $(".reg-code > span").html(html); // we append the html in the span
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) { // we handle error
            alert(request.responseText);
            }
          });
    });
});
```

PHP (hash.exe.php) will look like this (left you process as-is, added the echo'd answer):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$num = rand(0, 10000);
$hash = password_hash($num, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array(
'cost' => 6
));

echo"$hash"; // this 'invisible' HTML output is echo'd back to the page who initiated it
?>
```

> Example putting all together [FIDDLE](https://pastebin.com/XU9SBZFQ)

Answer (score 0):

It should be get. Because it does not change server state. Just return new value.

```
$('.fa-refresh').click(function(){
   $.get( "./path/to/hashscript.php", function( data ) {
    $( ".reg-code > span" ).html( "Hash:" + data );
   });
});
```

and the hashscript.php file should contain

```
echo md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
```

Comment: Nice copy, and your change is incorrect. `hashscript.php` should echo `$hash` and not a random hash value.

Comment: Yes it is a copy. But if you open your eyes and see, you will find whats the difference.And the does not make difference you can print whatever you want its just an idea.