# Clicking a <i> tag to generate a new hash (won't work)

Tags: php, html, ajax

For some reason this just makes the text in the `<span>` blank. I'm trying to make it so when you click on the `<i>` tag, it generates a new hash into the `<span>` tag.

**HTML:**

```
<p class="reg-code">Hash: <span><?php echo $hash; ?></span><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" id="refresh-hash"></i></p>
```

**AJAX:**

```
$('#refresh-hash').click(function(){
  $.post( "../api/register_hash.php", function(data) {
    $(".reg-code > span").html(data);
  });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$num = rand(0, 10000);
$hash = password_hash($num, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array(
    'cost' => 6
));
```

Comment: i dont see `#refresh-hash` in your HTML

Comment: Please add html for refresh-hash tag as well.

Comment: mb copied wrong version, fixed it on this post but its still broken obv

Comment: still dunno whats wrong :U

Comment: whats your output for `console.log(data)`

Comment: the console.log was blank

Comment: Original question based on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44019447/clicking-a-text-tag-to-generate-new-hash/44022053).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things you can do to make things work:

```
# Look for an action word
if($_POST['action'] == 'get_hash') {
    $num = rand(0, 10000);
    $hash = password_hash($num, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array(
        'cost' => 6
    ));
    # Die (echo here)
    die($hash);
}
```

I don't know what is supposed to be in your `<i id="refresh-hash">` block, but there is nothing there to click, the `<i>` is empty. I added the word "REFRESH" so there was something to click.

```
<p class="reg-code">Hash: <span><?php echo $hash ?></span><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" id="refresh-hash">REFRESH</i></p>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Try using "on()" here
    $('#refresh-hash').on('click',function(){
        // Send data (action word)
        // Also make sure the "../api/register_hash.php" is actually the
        // correct path
        $.post("../api/register_hash.php", {"action":'get_hash'},function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $(".reg-code > span").html(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

In case you are wondering, I did check this and it does work if properly implemented. Likely your main problem is that you are not echoing the return on the php side (`die($hash);`).

Comment: Thanks for the help.